# How to Create and display Tree view (using JAVA, Aurelia)

Tags: javascript, java, tree, treeview, aurelia

I have a Map Collection of parents and children in my Java code of format

```
    Family{
    String id;
    String Name;
    String parent Name;
    String childName;
    }
```

i need to display this data in tree format in my html using javascript so that they appear as

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G3Mh.png)

so can any one please help me to create a tree Map such that the children are nested inside the parent and so on and display them using aurelia and also how to implement tree view in aurelia ?

i have no idea how to create nodes or nested tree object.

Answer (score 0):

With Java I don't know but you can reefer below gist run link for tree structure.

**https://gist.run/?id=53dc5b81ef1549cdcc56c3b1fa1e67ba**